# Loop over a Map of Objects

Tags: terraform

How do I do a `for_each` loop for the following?

I want to create a `tfe_variable` `node_count` & `vm_size`.
I need both these tfe_variables in both `wksp1` and `wksp2`

```
variable "custom_variables" {
  type = map(object({
    node_count = number
    vm_size    = string
  }))

  default = {
    wksp1 = {
      node_count = 2
      vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v3"
    },
    wksp2 = {
      node_count = 5
      vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v5"
    }
  }
}

resource "tfe_variable" "custom" {
  for_each = {
    # for each workspace & variable in var.custom_variables create a tfe_variable
  }

  key          = each.value.name
  value        = each.value.value
  category     = "terraform"
  workspace_id = each.value.workspace_id
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main requirement to keep in mind for `for_each` is that we always need to create a map that has one element for each instance of the resource we want to create. In this case, that means you need a map with one element *per workspace per variable*, because `tfe_variable` describes a single variable on a single workspace.

Our job then is to write an expression to project the map-of-objects value coming in via the variable to a collection that has a separate element per variable. Here's one way to get that done, using [the `flatten` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html) in a way similar to [an example in its documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each):

```
locals {
  workspace_variables = flatten([
    for ws_name, ws in var.custom_variables : [
      for var_name, value in ws : {
        workspace = ws_name
        variable  = var_name
        value     = value
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

The above should produce a `local.workspace_variables` that looks like this:

```
[
  { workspace = "wksp1", variable = "node_count", value = 2 },
  { workspace = "wksp1", variable = "vm_size", value = "Standard_D2_v3" },
  { workspace = "wksp2", variable = "node_count", value = 5 },
  { workspace = "wksp2", variable = "vm_size", value = "Standard_D2_v5" },
]
```

This now meets the requirement of having one element per desired `tfe_variable` instance, so our only remaining job is to project this into a map to provide unique identifiers for each element and describe how to populate the `tfe_variable` arguments based on these objects:

```
resource "tfe_variable" "custom" {
  for_each = {
    for wsv in local.workspace_variables : "${wsv.workspace}.${wsv.variable}" => wsv
  }

  key          = each.value.variable
  value        = each.value.value
  category     = "terraform"
  workspace_id = each.value.workspace
}
```

---

One thing I didn't contend with above, because it wasn't directly you question, is the value of `workspace_id` in `tfe_variable`. If I recall correctly, that argument is expecting a workspace *id* rather than a workspace *name*, in which case you might need a slightly more complicated expression for the `workspace_id` argument. If you already have a `tfe_workspace` resource using the workspace names as keys then something like this might work, for example:

```
  workspace_id = tfe_workspace.example[each.value.workspace].id
```

If your workspaces are created in a different way then you may have to do something more complicated here, but that's getting far off the topic of your original question so I won't try to dig into that here. I'm happy to try to help with it in a separate question on this site though, if you like.

Answer (score 5):

You're really close! Here are a couple of things to consider:

**Option 1: Multiple `tfe_variable` resources**

1. Create a `tfe_variable` resource for each variable you want to create
2. Make sure the key in you `custom_variables` map is the workspace ID.

```
variable "custom_variables" {
  type = map(object({
    node_count = number
    vm_size    = string
  }))

  default = {
    wksp1_id = {
      node_count = 2
      vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v3"
    },
    wksp2_id = {
      node_count = 5
      vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v5"
    }
  }
}

resource "tfe_variable" "node_count" {
  for_each = var.custom_variables

  key          = "node_count"
  value        = each.value.node_count
  category     = "terraform"
  workspace_id = each.key
}

resource "tfe_variable" "vm_size" {
  for_each = var.custom_variables

  key          = "vm_size"
  value        = each.value.vm_size
  category     = "terraform"
  workspace_id = each.key
}
```

The drawback to this option is that you'll need an additional resource for each variable.

**Option 2: A list of variable objects**

1. Define a list of the keys, values, and workspace IDs of each variable
2. Use `count` to iterate the list

```
variable "custom_variables" {
  type = list(object({
    key          = string
    value        = string
    workspace_id = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      key          = "node_count"
      value        = "2"
      workspace_id = "wksp1_id"
    },
    {
      key          = "node_count"
      value        = "5"
      workspace_id = "wksp2_id"
    },
    {
      key          = "vm_size"
      value        = "Standard_D2_v3"
      workspace_id = "wksp1_id"
    },
    {
      key          = "vm_size"
      value        = "Standard_D2_v5"
      workspace_id = "wksp2_id"
    }
  ]
}

resource "tfe_variable" "custom" {
  count = length(var.custom_variables)

  key          = var.custom_variables[count.index].key
  value        = var.custom_variables[count.index].value
  workspace_id = var.custom_variables[count.index].workspace_id
  category     = "terraform"
}
```

There are a couple of drawbacks to this approach as well:

- There is a fair amount of duplicated code in the variable definition
- The value must always be of the same type

If you're struggling with loop concepts in Terraform, [this blog post](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9) might help you.

Comment: anyway to do this without hardcoding the keys "node_count" & "vm_size" in the plan. For example if I just update custom_variables with new variable later on

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer with an alternative option. There are drawbacks to this method as well, unfortunately, but I don't see an optimal approach.